# question about the command :sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rqt-common-plugin

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run the command :sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rqt-common-plugin,but the answer is:
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-rqt-common-plugin.
I don't know why ,anybody who knows please tell me how to solve it. thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220023/question-about-the-command-:sudo-apt-get-install-ros-indigo-rqt-common-plugin/) by [xuao](https://answers.ros.org/users/24740/xuao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package name is rqt_common_plugins (note that it is plural).

The proper command to install it from debs on Indigo is:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rqt-common-plugins
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xuao](https://answers.ros.org/users/24740/xuao/) on 2015-10-28**:
hahaha,i missed the "s",now,it runs correctly.